# How can I get the length of a model defined in manifest.json?

Tags: sapui5

I have a model defined in the manifest.json file ('products').

**manifest.json**

```
"dataSources": {
    "productsModel": {
        "type" : "JSON",
        "uri": "model/products.json"
    },

  ...

 "models": {
    "products": {
        "dataSource":  "productsModel"
        }
```

In my controller, I would like to access the length of the "products" model. But I get 'undefined'. I feel like this should be relatively simple, but I have not found a direct answer to this.

**main.controller.js**

```
var mainController = BaseController.extend("vizConcept.controller.Main", {

        onInit: function(oEvent) {

          this.getView().setModel(this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("products"), "products");
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel("products");
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);

            //this logs as 'undefined'
            console.log(oModel.length);
```

**products.json**

```
{
    "products": [
        { 
            "Item": "1",
            "AwdDate": "20160715",
            "Hist": 171.9,
            "Current": 183

        },
        {
            "Item": "2",
            "AwdDate": "20160701",
            "Hist" : 144.3,
            "Current": 158.6
        },
        {
            "Item": "3",
            "AwdDate": "20150701",
            "Hist": 160,
            "Current": 165
        },
        { 
            "Item": "1",
            "AwdDate": "20160715",
            "Hist": 201,
            "Current": 167
        },
        {
             "Item": "2",
            "AwdDate": "20160801",
            "Hist" : 175.3,
            "Current": 178.2
        },
        {
            "Item": "3",
            "AwdDate": "20150721",
            "Hist": 160,
            "Current": 147
        },
        { 
            "Item": "1",
            "AwdDate": "20160715",
            "Hist": 175.9,
            "Current": 185.2
        },
        {
            "Item": "2",
            "AwdDate": "20161101",
            "Hist" : 165.3,
            "Current": 158.2
        },
        {
            "Item": "3",
            "AwdDate": "201700101",
            "Hist": 160,
            "Current": 165
        },
        {
            "Item": "4",
            "AwdDate": "201600401",
            "Hist": 173,
            "Current": 177
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the local JSON file as a model and I configured in the manifest file. But the problem is we will get the model in the **onInit** but not the data. It will take its own sweet time to load then it will add the data.

If you want to perform any operation after getting the data means you have to attach the event **RequestCompleted** on your model object as below.

```
onInit: function() {
    var model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("products");
    this.getView().setModel(model , "products");
    model.attachRequestCompleted(this._dataLoaded, this);
    model.attachRequestFailed(this._errorWhileDataLoading, this);
}

_dataLoaded: function(oEvent) {
    var model = this.getView().getModel("products");
    console.log(model.getData().length);
}

_errorWhileDataLoading: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("Error handling");
}
```

And if there is any error you can get it from the event **RequestFailed**.